# Javascript Parent-Child items

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have a table with rows that looks like this

```
<tr>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td><span class="label-success">Active</span></td>
<td><a href="#" onclick(my-js-here.js)>change status</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td>xyz</td>
<td><span class="label-pending">Active</span></td>
<td><a href="#" onclick(my-js-here.js)>another change status</a></td>
</tr>
```

When I click the "change status" link, I want to be able to change the class "lable-success" to "label-fail"

in my-js-here.js, how do I reference/pick out this  in the  in this same row

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").(this is where I am lost).removeClass('lable-success');
$(this).parents("tr:first").(this is where I am lost).addClass('fail');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('span').toggleClass('label-success fail');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Fyv2P/)**

This will allow you to toggle the classes. If you just want to be able to make the change once, change `.find('span')` to `.find('.label-success')`